Is there a way to combine the PlayerAttack with the NpcAttack without having to reduce the Player and Npc structs to a single struct?
I'd like to be able to make an Attack trait both Npc and Player could be sent to instead of them having to have their own individual traits for attacking.
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct Player {
    hp: i32,
    atk_pow: i32,
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct Npc {
    hp: i32,
    atk_pow: i32,
}

trait PlayerAttack {
    fn damage(&self, enemy: Npc) -> i32;
}

impl PlayerAttack for Player {
    fn damage(&self, mut npc: Npc) -> i32 {
        npc.hp -= self.atk_pow;
        npc.hp
    }
}

trait NpcAttack {
    fn damage(&self, player: Player) -> i32;
}

impl NpcAttack for Npc {
    fn damage(&self, mut player: Player) -> i32 {
        player.hp -= self.atk_pow;
        player.hp
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut player = Player { hp: 5, atk_pow: 2 };
    let mut goblin = Npc { hp: 4, atk_pow: 1 };

    goblin.hp = player.damage(goblin);
    player.hp = goblin.damage(player);
    println!("Goblin HP: {}", goblin.hp);
    println!("Player HP: {}", player.hp);
}

I made a struct that was just a generic Character and that worked, but I was hoping to keep Player and Npc separate from each other so I could add different fields to them when the time comes, and also it just reads better with them separate.

Use either an associated type or a generic parameter.
Associated type, use this if each type can only have one type of enemy:
trait Attack {
    type Enemy;
    fn damage(&self, enemy: Self::Enemy) -> i32;
}

impl Attack for Player {
    type Enemy = Npc;
    fn damage(&self, mut npc: Npc) -> i32 {
        npc.hp -= self.atk_pow;
        npc.hp
    }
}

impl Attack for Npc {
    type Enemy = Player;
    fn damage(&self, mut player: Player) -> i32 {
        player.hp -= self.atk_pow;
        player.hp
    }
}

Generic parameter, use this if some type can have more than one type of enemy:
trait Attack<Enemy> {
    fn damage(&self, enemy: Enemy) -> i32;
}

impl Attack<Npc> for Player {
    fn damage(&self, mut npc: Npc) -> i32 {
        npc.hp -= self.atk_pow;
        npc.hp
    }
}

impl Attack<Player> for Npc {
    fn damage(&self, mut player: Player) -> i32 {
        player.hp -= self.atk_pow;
        player.hp
    }
}

Also, it is probably better to mutate the enemy in-place:
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct Player {
    hp: i32,
    atk_pow: i32,
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct Npc {
    hp: i32,
    atk_pow: i32,
}

trait Attack<Enemy> {
    fn damage(&self, enemy: &mut Enemy);
}

impl Attack<Npc> for Player {
    fn damage(&self, npc: &mut Npc) {
        npc.hp -= self.atk_pow;
    }
}

impl Attack<Player> for Npc {
    fn damage(&self, player: &mut Player) {
        player.hp -= self.atk_pow;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut player = Player { hp: 5, atk_pow: 2 };
    let mut goblin = Npc { hp: 4, atk_pow: 1 };

    player.damage(&mut goblin);
    goblin.damage(&mut player);
    println!("Goblin HP: {}", goblin.hp);
    println!("Player HP: {}", player.hp);
}


Awesome, thank you!
